# Overloaded function declarations in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

I am trying to understand *overloading* in TypeScript and encountered problems pretty early. I would like to make an *overload* from the following type declaration:

```js
type T = {
  (value: number): number
  (value: string): string
}
```

Besides other things I tried the following, but all attempts failed:

```js
let bar: T = (value: number | string): number | string => {
  if (typeof value === "number") return value
  return value
}
```

If it is not clear yet, I would like to declare a function which returns a string if the argument is a string and returns a number if the argument is a number.

I know I could solve this problem on other ways, e.g.:

```js
type Input = string | number

function foobar<T extends Input>(input: T): T {
  return input
}
```

... but I would love to find a solution for my concrete question.

Thank you!

Comment: Could you clarify the question? As it put now the solution is as simple as `const bar: T = (value: any) => value;` [Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/C4TwDgpgBAKlC8UDeAoKUAUA3AhgGwFcIAuKAOwIFsAjCAJwEpSKb61NdCSoBnYOgJZkA5k178hwlAF8UKAMYB7MnyjUcdUnETZ8RUjjIgGCAHxRORANxz1dDAHIHDFHYwBGF2-5EGQA)

Comment: @AlekseyL. Thank you, this actually works. I would love to think that I tried this before, but I was so fixated on using unions inside the call signature of `bar`, but I just should have used `any` instead.

Comment: Why does the compiler not throw an error in the following example? `const bar: T = (value: any) => {
  if (typeof value === "number") return [2];
  return value
}
`